# AngularFire 2 Accessing Data Outside .subscribe()

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm pulling user data from database with this code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})

export class ProfilePage {
  profileData: Observable<any[]>

  constructor(private fire:AngularFireAuth,private db :AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).snapshotChanges().map(action => {
      const $key = action.payload.key;
      const data = { $key, ...action.payload.val() };
      return data;
    }))
    .subscribe(profile =>{
      this.profileData = profile;
      console.log(this.profileData.username); // this is working.
    });
    console.log(this.profileData.username); // this is undefined
    // How to access username outside subscribe function ?
  }
}
```

My question is: How to access username outside subscribe function to use it somewhere else ? I added comments on code.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because the profileData is needs some time to get its value and the `subscribe()` method is called when the data arrives.
But the `console.log()` outside of the subscribe callback is getting executed directly.

But you can use `profileData` in your template if needed. It will update when the data has arrived and the `subscribe()` function has been executed.

Comment: You can only use it in code once it gets defined in the `.subscribe()` method. You could call other functions from there, which use or transform the profileData.

Answer (score -1):

Import like this,

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

in class declare variable like,

```
profileData: FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;
```

Comment: isnt this the old way ?